# Display form data in table using session and then delete it on button click using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, web, session

**I apologize if this  is asked already, but I want to take user input in html form and insert it  into table using session (without any usage of database) in format given in image attatched.**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10Ry.png

> I tried code below to insert form data into table using php sessions.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['fname'])) {
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $pswd = $_SESSION['pswd'];
    $country = $_SESSION['country'];
    $phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $dob = $_SESSION['dob'];
}
else {
    $fname = [];
    $lname = [];
    $username = [];
    $pswd = [];
    $country = [];
    $phone = [];
    $email = [];
    $dob = [];
}
if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
    $fname[] = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname[] = $_POST['lname'];
    $username[] = $_POST['username'];
    $pswd[] = $_POST['pswd'];
    $country[] = $_POST['country'];
    $phone[] = $_POST['phone'];
    $email[] = $_POST['email'];
    $dob[] = $_POST['dob'];
}

$_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
$_SESSION['lname'] = $lname;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['pswd'] = $pswd;
$_SESSION['country'] = $country;
$_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['dob'] = $dob;


?>
<table class="table" id="mytable">
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                <th scope="col">Password</th>
                <th scope="col">Country</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">DOB</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
                $count = 0;
                foreach($fname as $key=>$value){
                    $count++;
                    // print "<br> $count: $name[$key], $email[$key]";
                    
                    echo "<tr><td>$count</td><td>$fname[$key]</td><td>$lname[$key]</td><td>$username[$key]</td>
                    <td>$pswd[$key]</td><td>$country[$key]</td><td>$phone[$key]</td><td>$email[$key]</td>
                    <td>$dob[$key]</td><td><button class = 'btn btn-danger' onclick = 'deler()'>del</button></td></tr>";
                }
            ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**But I can't really figure out a way to click the delete  button and delete that particular row from table as well as corresponding data from session array as well.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues here.

### One

To use the POST, you have to have a form that posts, put this around the table.

```html
<form method='post'>
 ...
</form>
```

### Two

Each button should have a unique name, this name is what you use to figure out which row is being deleted.  Each button will have the name btn- followed by the key, such as **btn-12**.  This what you use back on the server in PHP to determine the row.

```php
<td>$dob[$key]</td><td><button class = 'btn btn-danger' type='submit'
   name='btn-$key'>del</button></td></tr>";
```

### Three

I am not sure what onclick event is for, there appears to be no javascript function here.  If this is incorrect, then please show us the javascript.

Comment: Hi @rohit, the JS function that appears to be called in onclick ="" was  just for experiment purpose, I removed it later on. I am attaching the piece of code that helped me do the job below my query in post. Thanks for guidance!